# How to properly fetch Qt using CMake?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, compiler-errors, c++20

I am facing the following problem: I am trying to use the `CMake` function `FetchContent_Declare` to fetch `Qt` C++ library and in particular the version 6.4.2. I am following the guide from [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_6_from_Git#:%7E:text=perl%20init%2Drepository-,Configuring%20and%20Building,Where%20dot%20after%20%22%2D%2Dbuild%22%20means%20current%20folder.,-On%20Windows%3A) site in which is explained how to build Qt from source and it works well if performed "by hand" without `CMake`; but if I want to incorporate it with `FetchContent_Declare` things became harder since before compiling, as you can see from the link, I need to run the initialization command:

```
perl init-repository
```

and the configuration one (before building):

```
mkdir qt6-build
cd qt6-build
../qt6/configure
```

How can I incorporate these two steps into the fetch content part of CMake?

My current `CMake` script is:

```
include( FetchContent )

FetchContent_Declare(
  Qt6
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/qt/qt5"
  GIT_TAG v6.4.2
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND "perl init-repository && ./configure"
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable( Qt6 )
```

but it seems not correctly working:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1087 (message):
  Build step for qt6 failed: 2
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1216:EVAL:2 (__FetchContent_directPopulate)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1216 (cmake_language)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1259 (FetchContent_Populate)
  deps/qt6/CMakeLists.txt:19 (FetchContent_MakeAvailable)
```

I need also a way, if possible, to not ask GitHube username and password when configuring and installing the library through `FetchContent_Declare`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev an error, sorry deleted

Comment: Configure step is disabled in FetchContent: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_declare. The whole purpose of FetchContent is to download and unpack the external project, but it is the main project which is responsible for configuration and further steps. QT project could be perfectly built with CMake, why do you ever specify `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Because I thought that configure steps I mentioned before were needed before compiling and were not included in `FetchContent_Declare` step. So should I remove `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` and it should work?

Comment: Yes, you could remove CONFIGURE_COMMAND and try to build your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution! This `CMakeLists.txt` works perfectly for this purpose:

```
# Project settings
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.15 )

project( key-manager-dependencies-qt6
    VERSION 1.0
    DESCRIPTION "Build system for key-manager Qt6 dependency."
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

# Error if building out of a build directory
file( TO_CMAKE_PATH "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt" LOC_PATH )
if( EXISTS "${LOC_PATH}" )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "You cannot build in a source directory (or any directory with "
                         "CMakeLists.txt file). Please make a build subdirectory. Feel free to "
                         "remove CMakeCache.txt and CMakeFiles." )
endif()

# Fetch the package
find_package( Qt6 6.4.2 QUIET )

if( NOT Qt6_FOUND )

    # Set Ninja for compilation
    set( CMAKE_GENERATOR "Ninja" CACHE STRING "CMake generator" FORCE )

    # Initial message
    message( STATUS "Qt 6.4.2 not found. Downloading and configuring Qt..." )

    # Download and extract archive of Qt 6.4.2
    set( QT_VERSION "6.4.2" )
    set( QT_ARCHIVE_URL "https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/6.4/${QT_VERSION}/submodules/qtbase-everywhere-src-${QT_VERSION}.tar.xz" )
    set( QT_ARCHIVE_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qtbase-everywhere-src-${QT_VERSION}.tar.xz" )
    set( QT_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qtbase-everywhere-src-${QT_VERSION}" )
    message( STATUS "Downloading the package from the official repository..." )
    file( DOWNLOAD ${QT_ARCHIVE_URL} ${QT_ARCHIVE_FILE}
          SHOW_PROGRESS
          EXPECTED_HASH SHA256=a88bc6cedbb34878a49a622baa79cace78cfbad4f95fdbd3656ddb21c705525d )
    message( STATUS "Unpacking the release..." )
    execute_process( COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xvf ${QT_ARCHIVE_FILE}
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} 
                     OUTPUT_QUIET
    )

    # Configure Qt (skip building of useless modules)
    set( QT_BUILD_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qt-build" )
    file( MAKE_DIRECTORY ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )
    message( STATUS "Configuring..." )
    execute_process( COMMAND ${QT_SOURCE_DIR}/configure -prefix ${QT_BUILD_DIR}
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )

    # Check if system supports parallelization
    if( DEFINED ENV{NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS} )
        set( JOBS_OPTION "-j$ENV{NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS}" )
    elseif( DEFINED ENV{PROCESSOR_COUNT} )
        set( JOBS_OPTION "-j$ENV{PROCESSOR_COUNT}" )
    else()
        set( JOBS_OPTION "" )
    endif()

    # Use -j option to compile if possible (qt is very big)
    if( JOBS_OPTION )
        message( STATUS "Compiling with parallelization..." )
        execute_process( COMMAND ninja ${JOBS_OPTION}
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )
    else()
        message( STATUS "Compiling without parallelization..." )
        execute_process( COMMAND ninja
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )
    endif()

    # Set necessary environment variables to use Qt
    set( ENV{QTDIR} ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )
    set( ENV{PATH} ${QT_BUILD_DIR}/bin:$ENV{PATH})

else()
    message( STATUS "Qt 6.4.2 found in the system." )
endif()
```

it is all well commented so hope this can be useful for other people.

**NOTE**: this script fetch Qt 6.4.2, but you can modify it with any required version.

**NOTE 2**: if you want to speed up the process you can ask to skip compilation of tests, examples and optional Qt modules by modifying this line:

```
execute_process( COMMAND ${QT_SOURCE_DIR}/configure -prefix ${QT_BUILD_DIR} WORKING_DIRECTORY ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )
```

Comment: WHy do you force Ninja as the cmake generator?