# Integrating Qt with SFML using cmake for cross-platform development

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, sfml

I want to integrate the Qt framework with SFML, using cmake, hopefully in VS2022. Currently I have SFML already in my repository, and the cmake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(CMakeSFMLProject LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" OFF)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(SFML
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
    GIT_TAG 2.6.x)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

add_executable(CMakeSFMLProject src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CMakeSFMLProject PRIVATE sfml-graphics)
target_compile_features(CMakeSFMLProject PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

if(WIN32)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET CMakeSFMLProject
        COMMENT "Copy OpenAL DLL"
        PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SFML_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/bin/$<IF:$<EQUAL:${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P},8>,x64,x86>/openal32.dll $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:CMakeSFMLProject>
        VERBATIM)
endif()

install(TARGETS CMakeSFMLProject)
```

So in to this, I want to somehow add the Qt library.

I also want to program in VS, for now, I just open the folder where this repository is, and VS works just fine with it. I have already installed Qt for VS, and it works, but I don't know how to integrate the two frameworks together, and also I am not sure how to use them after I put them together.

Currently after update I have the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(PathFinder VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" OFF)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(SFML
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
    GIT_TAG 2.6.x)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

add_executable(PathFinder src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(PathFinder PRIVATE
    Qt6::Core
    Qt6::Widgets
    sfml-graphics
)
target_compile_features(PathFinder PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

if(WIN32)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET PathFinder
        COMMENT "Copy OpenAL DLL"
        PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SFML_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/bin/$<IF:$<EQUAL:${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P},8>,x64,x86>/openal32.dll $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:CMakeSFMLProject>
        VERBATIM)
endif()

install(TARGETS PathFinder)
```

but for some reason I get

```
  By not providing "FindQt6.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt6Config.cmake
    qt6-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt6" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt6_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt6" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.   PathFinder  C:\Users\nhorv\Desktop\proba\CMakeLists.txt 7
```

but I want to include Qt locally, so the user doesn't have to manually set the PATH variable. I want to install Qt as a dependency, and not installing it system-wide. Is this possible with the git repo of Qt?

Comment: ***I have already installed Qt for VS, and it works,*** That is not really necessary.  At work I have used Qt with Visual Studio since 2008. I rarely have that addon installed. Instead I have used CMake from the start.

Comment: ***but I don't know how to integrate the two frameworks together*** Just look at any CMakeLists.txt for Qt: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-get-started.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-get-started.html)

Comment: Most times when you get this error message if you do exactly as it told you you solve the problem. This question may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924776/is-it-possible-to-alter-cmake-module-path-from-cmake-commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924776/is-it-possible-to-alter-cmake-module-path-from-cmake-commandline)

Comment: ***I want to install Qt as a dependency, and not installing it system-wide. Is this possible with the git repo of Qt?*** The answer to that is most likely yes. Although it's likely non-trivial. That topic probably should be a new / different question. Your original question and problem has been answered and solved sufficiently.

Comment: I believe the following question is a duplicate for the new question / problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75743502/how-to-properly-fetch-qt-using-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75743502/how-to-properly-fetch-qt-using-cmake)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(SFMLQt VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

# Find SFML
find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(SFMLQt
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(SFMLQt SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    else()
        add_executable(SFMLQt
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(SFMLQt PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets sfml-graphics)

# Set target properties
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
    set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.SFMLQt)
endif()
set_target_properties(SFMLQt PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS SFMLQt
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(SFMLQt)
endif()
```

And this is minimal example:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int  main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow  window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Example");

    sf::CircleShape  shape(50.f);

    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event  event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

But the point is that my OS is Ubuntu 22.04, for Windows, you need to do it the same way.
Meaning something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(CMakeSFMLProject LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" OFF)

# Find Qt
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(SFML
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
    GIT_TAG 2.6.x)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

add_executable(CMakeSFMLProject src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CMakeSFMLProject PRIVATE sfml-graphics Qt5::Widgets)
target_compile_features(CMakeSFMLProject PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

if(WIN32)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET CMakeSFMLProject
        COMMENT "Copy OpenAL DLL"
        PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SFML_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/bin/$<IF:$<EQUAL:${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P},8>,x64,x86>/openal32.dll $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:CMakeSFMLProject>
        VERBATIM)
endif()

install(TARGETS CMakeSFMLProject)
```